# My passport contains a surname, while my other documents do not. What should I do when applying for Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, passports, paperwork, italy, schengen-visas

There is surname in my passport but my actual name does not include a surname. This actual name without a surname is the one written in my occupational documentation and bank statement. I'm now applying for a Schengen tourist visa, and the Italian Embassy is asking me to provide said documents. (With the same name as that which is in my passport.)

What should i do?

Comment: It seems your passport is incorrect; the obvious answer would be to get a new passport with the correct name. Is there some reason why you haven't done that already?

Comment: passport people added my surname as my family name and fathers name is having surname...what should i do now as my detailed itenary is booked and i have to travel in next week

Comment: @phoog In some places, surnames don't exist. For example, in India, many people simply have a given name. This given name is then preceded by the initial(s) of their father's given name(s). To comply with the standards of international passports, there's a field called "surname" which then often contains the father's given name. However, Indian institutions may not have this "surname" field. Something like this may be the premise of OP's question?

Comment: If you have to travel next week then you have waited far too long to apply for your visa.  Even if all your documents were in perfect order with matching names, you would have a problem now.  According to http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/mumbai/, you should submit the application at least 15 working days (three weeks) before travel, and according to http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/mumbai/news.html the application will be accepted only if you submit it at least ten to twelve days before your travel, depending on where you submit it.

Answer (score 2):

Most schengen countries nowadays ask passport along with identity card plus photocopy so that they would be able to confirm applicant identity.

Also some embassies and consulates further requires family registration certificate registered with the relevant local authorities at your home country, to make sure application name and family name match accordingly.

Once your identity is confirmed, they would be matching your passport full name with your provided financial documents and bank statements. Moreover schengen embassy/consulate usually ask bank statement along with maintenance certificate confirming your full name signed by bank manager.

You have stated that you intended to apply to Italian embassy and they require all your documents should match  your passport details are presumably correct.

If you have some extra time available, you could always amend your name with your local bank. Usually you will send a request for full name instead of first name and sometime they would update in their system. However some banks need you to open a separate account if you need a name change. The best possibility you could always get by visiting your branch immediately. Also you will have to show your full name in your covering letter as well as in occupation documents.

From my previous experience with different schengen countries, it would be highly unlikely they accept your application